# Symfony multiselect dropdown not working for second form type

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, dropdown, multi-select

I am rendering two form types on a page from my project. I do this because my users have to decide between two options, how to proceed, which are very similar and include 3 dropdowns for the same entities.

```
     <div id="upload_profile_yes" >
      <div id="up_markets_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(upForm.markets, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id="up_channel1_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(upForm.channel1, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id = "up_prod_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(upForm.products, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id ="up_container" class="col-md-12">
        {{ form_row(upForm.uploadprofile) }} <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="upload_profile_no">
      <div id="markets_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(form.markets, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id="channel1_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(form.channel1, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id = "prod_container" class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(form.products, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-inline'} }) }}
      </div>
      <div id="agencies_container" class="col-md-12">
        {{ form_row(form.agencies) }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-multiselect.js') }}"></script>

{# JS functions to validate IATA/UCID/tourcode (and possibly load funds) #}
{% include 'AppBundle:Utils:validation.js.twig' %}
{% include 'DocumentBundle:Document/Utils:agency_selection.js.twig' %}
{% include 'DocumentBundle:Document/Utils:uploadprofile_selection.js.twig' %}
```

So for the first choice (upload_profile_no) I use the javascript file **agency_selection.js.twig** (cut down to the necessary code)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ form.vars.name }}_markets', 'Select Markets' );
makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ form.vars.name }}_products', 'Select Products' );
makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ form.vars.name }}_channel1', 'Select Channel1');

</script>
```

this results in all of the three dropdowns becoming a multiselect like the way I want it. For the second choice (upload_profile_yes) I have the **uploadprofile_selection.js.twig** file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_markets');
makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_markets', 'Select Markets' );
makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_products', 'Select Products' );
makeMultiselectDropdown('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_channel1', 'Select Channel1' );

      </script>
```

but for this form, it's just simply not rendering the multiselect dropdowns.
The form is rendered correctly, so the dropdowns appear on the correct spot with the correct data, but the javascript for making them real dropdowns doesn't work.

The javascript file is working (I tested it with the alert() function, and that's working..)

that's how it looks like:

dropdowns for **upload_profile_no**[image]
not working dropdowns for **upload_profile_yes**
[image]

so as you can see, the values are all correct..

**Update**

What I also realized is that the form type isn't exactly rendered correctly.
When taking the form_row(upForm.markets) out, it doesn't appear at all on that page even though it should appear on the very bottom of the page as "unrendered"..

Comment: try to `console.log('#{{ form.vars.name }}_markets')` and `console.log('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_markets')`. values are different ?

Comment: that'S basically what I did with my alert, right? And yes, the output is always the correct form type (for the first one it's document_new and for the second document_uploadprofile)..

Comment: that's basically what you did with your alert, in your uploadprofile_selection.js.twig. as there was not any alert in the other file, i wanted to make sure you compared the 2 selectors.

Comment: what if you put a console.log in your makeMultiselectDropdown() function, to dump the first parameter ? what if you pass directly a jQuery object as the first param, instead of an identifier ? something like `makeMultiselectDropdown($('#{{ upForm.vars.name }}_markets'), 'Select Markets' );` still buggy ?

Comment: I just added some screenshots, to show that the data is all correct
Unfortunately I'm still quite new to javascript etc. so I don't really know what to do to get answers to your questions.. :/
your last suggestion with the object, I tried but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: which multiselect library are you using ?

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-multiselect.js') }}"></script>

Comment: what's also weird @VaN is that the labels aren't translated at all.. it still says label.markets but for the other form it's translating it correctly to "Markets"

Comment: yeah, i noticed about the labels, thought it was intentional. in order to get some advanced help, you should try to reproduce the bug in a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ with your custom html, css and js. you can load external resources in the navbar on the left, probably this one : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js . Once your jsfiddle is created and it reproduce the bug, post it here, ppl might try to debug it.

Comment: Ok, I\m trying to set up a JSFIddle, but how does the html I copy in there pick up on my Form Types?

Comment: just copy your final html code, used by the browser. not your php source code generating it.

Comment: Be sure that both form types returns other block prefixes in the getBlockPrefix method in your formType classes. Otherwise there will be formfields with exactly the same id's and that makes them unreachable with javascript

Comment: @sonja did you manage to setup the jsfiddle ? or did you find the bug ?

Comment: @VaN I didn't manage to setup a JSFiddle that worked exactly as in my project. But I just solved my problem by putting all javascript in one class! I'm not yet sure why this helped but I'm glad for now! I just ran into another problem concerning my two form types. would you mind helping me in a private chat?

Comment: sure, though i have no idea how to trigger a stackoverflow chat session. edit :  can you try to join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70110/sonja-form-type ?